# Flutter почему callback функция вызывается при создании виджета?

Tags: flutter, callback

В первый раз вижу callback во flutter и не могу понять как они реализуются. У меня есть callback который печатает в консоль всё, что в него передадут

```
onDelete(dynamic val) {
print(val);
}
```

Передаю его в виджет

```
trailing: PopMenuWidget(                          
 onDelete: onDelete(item),
)),
```

Когда создаеётся PopMenuWidget колбэк `onDelete` автоматически выстреливает. Причем несколько раз подряд. В таком поведении страном ничего страшного особо нет, но мой колбек обычный, если же я в него передаю setState() то виджет крашится в момент создания `error setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build`.

Comment: передавая колбэк в параметр нельзя ставить скобки, т.к. в этом случае вместо ссылки на функцию **onDelete** передаестя результат её выполнения.

Comment: @Spatz cпасибо! То есть, если у меня `final VoidCallback onDelete` то передать в него ничего не получится? Мне бы хотелось передавать, что-нибудь в колбэк функцию.

Comment: Параметры в колбэк передаются в момент самого события и их может быть произвольное количество.

Comment: Что за виджет такой ``PopMenuWidget``, если это ваш, то приведите его код.

Comment: Правильно он называется PopupMenuButton. Это виджет как всплывающее меню в которое можно добавлять свои варианты, например как по правому клику в виндовс. Не думаю что будет интересно, я вчера создавал вопрос в анг версии, когда совсем не мог понять, что происходит. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011478/flutter-callback-with-return-error-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-bu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавая колбэк виджету нужно либо указывать ссылку на существующую функцию, либо определять её "по месту", например так:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
      onSelected: (val) => print('Selected item is $val'),
      // ...
    );
  }
```

А в вашем случае передается результат выполнения самой функции, что допускается только когда функция возвращает другую функцию.

Comment: Определять по месту не работает. The argument type 'void Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'. Я все равно не пойму. У меня есть функция, я ее передаю как колбэк, зачем он её вызывает автоматически?

Comment: В вашем коде передается НЕ ФУНКЦИЯ а РЕЗУЛЬТАТ её выполнения, т.е. пустое значение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все так как вы и сказали. Я передавал результат выполнения функции, вместе ссылки на неё. А так как там был setState(), то сообщало, "ошибка зачем вы меняете состояние при создании виджета?". Единственно, вот такой вариант работает передачи функции как колбэка  `onDelete: () => onDelete(item)`